# Django Mock QuerySet

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Players class:

```
class Players:
  def __init__(self):
      self.players = PlayerModel.objects.all()

  def count(self):
      return len(self.players)
```

Test:

```
    def setUp(self):
      self.players = Players()

@patch('riskgame.entities.Players.count', return_value=9, create=True)
def test_count(self):
    number = self.players.count()
    self.assertEqual(number, 9)
```

This test throws:

```
Failed: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.
```

But why needs this test the database? It seems like that the @patch on Players.count() is'nt working. Is there a better solution to make this more testable?

Comment: When you initialise a `Player` object in `setUp()` you call the `__init__()` method of the object. That makes a call to the db: `PlayerModel.objects.all()`.

Comment: How can I ignore that?

Comment: You'd need to mock the `PlayerModel`'s `objects` manager.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @Janp95 you can look up how to implement custom managers in Django, for starters. Read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Fixt it with overriding the property players with

`def setUp(self):
      self.players = []`